# Failed to install POCO C++ through vcpkg

Tags: c++, poco-libraries, vcpkg

I am trying to install POCO libraries for C++ through vcpkg, through this command in Windows PowerShell :

`.\vcpkg install poco:x64-windows`

And I am getting this error :

`Error: Building package pcre:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED`

What should I do?

(This is the full command's output)

````
The following packages will be built and installed:
  * pcre[core]:x64-windows -> 8.45
    poco[core]:x64-windows -> 1.11.0
  * vcpkg-cmake[core]:x64-windows -> 2021-09-13
  * vcpkg-cmake-config[core]:x64-windows -> 2021-09-27
  * zlib[core]:x64-windows -> 1.2.11#13
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
Restored 0 packages from C:\Users\AB\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 244.5 us. Use --debug to see more details.
Starting package 1/5: pcre:x64-windows
Building package pcre[core]:x64-windows...
CMake Warning at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_download_distfile.cmake:170 (message):
  SILENT_EXIT has been deprecated as an argument to vcpkg_download_distfile
  -- remove the argument to resolve this warning
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ports/pcre/portfile.cmake:12 (vcpkg_download_distfile)
  scripts/ports.cmake:142 (include)


-- Downloading https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-8.45.zip -> pcre-8.45.zip...
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'binarycaching' unset
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'manifests' = off
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'compilertracking' unset
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'registries' unset
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'versions' unset
[DEBUG] Downloading https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-8.45.zip
[DEBUG] Download failed -- retrying after 1000 ms.
[DEBUG] Download failed -- retrying after 2000 ms.
[DEBUG] Download failed -- retrying after 4000 ms.
[DEBUG] D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vcpkg\base\downloads.cpp(656)
Error: Failed to download from mirror set:
https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-8.45.zip: WinHttpSendRequest() failed: 12002
https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-8.45.zip: WinHttpSendRequest() failed: 12002
https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-8.45.zip: WinHttpSendRequest() failed: 12002
https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-8.45.zip: WinHttpSendRequest() failed: 12002

[DEBUG] Exiting after %s (%d us)


CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_download_distfile.cmake:84 (message):

      Failed to download file with error: 1
      If you use a proxy, please check your proxy setting. Possible causes are:

      1. You are actually using an HTTP proxy, but setting HTTPS_PROXY variable
         to `https://address:port`. This is not correct, because `https://` prefix
         claims the proxy is an HTTPS proxy, while your proxy (v2ray, shadowsocksr
         , etc..) is an HTTP proxy. Try setting `http://address:port` to both
         HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY instead.

      2. You are using Fiddler. Currently a bug (https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/17752)
         will set HTTPS_PROXY to `https://fiddler_address:port` which lead to problem 1 above.
         Workaround is open Windows 10 Settings App, and search for Proxy Configuration page,
         Change `http=address:port;https=address:port` to `address`, and fill the port number.

      3. You proxy's remote server is out of service.

      In future vcpkg releases, if you are using Windows, you no longer need to set
      HTTP(S)_PROXY environment variables. Vcpkg will simply apply Windows IE Proxy
      Settings set by your proxy software. See (https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/pull/49)
      and (https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/pull/77)

      Otherwise, please submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_download_distfile.cmake:292 (z_vcpkg_download_distfile_show_proxy_and_fail)
  ports/pcre/portfile.cmake:12 (vcpkg_download_distfile)
  scripts/ports.cmake:142 (include)


Error: Building package pcre:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `git pull` and `.\vcpkg update`, then
submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
  package: pcre[core]:x64-windows -> 8.45
  vcpkg version: 2021-11-02-af04ebf6274fd6f7a941bff4662b3955c64f6f42
  vcpkg-tool version: 3730cbe99 2021-11-08 (49 minutes ago)

Additionally, attach any relevant sections from the log files above.```
````

Comment: If the site doesn't respond nothing can done about it

Comment: I am having same error, trying to install Gazebo via vcpkg. If there's any solution let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, vcpkg can not download some package files from the internet by itself, this is a common problem. When you have a problem like this, backtrack the vcpkg log, find the first error reported, if the error is a **download error**, backtrack, look for the `Downloading` log, you can find a log look like this:

```
- Downloading website -> package_name...
```

to solve this problem, you can download the package from the `website` manually, if the name of the package is not the `package_name`, rename the package name to the `package_name`, copy the package to this location: `VCPKG_ROOT/vcpkg/downloads/`, then run the install command again, the vcpkg will use the package file from the `download` folder directly rather than download it from the internet by itself.

From your log you can find that the first error is `Error: Failed to download from mirror set:`, this is a **download error**. The vcpkg can not download the **pcre-8.45.zip** from https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-8.45.zip. You can download the **pcre-8.45.zip** from https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-8.45.zip manually, then rename the file to **pcre-8.45.zip** and copy it into `VCPKG_ROOT/vcpkg/downloads/` folder. Then run the install command again.